# No tengo Oracle Services

Tags: oracle

Estaba instalando el *Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition 2* pero a la hora de querer ingresar por SQLPlus me bota "**ERROR: ORA-12560**", según he visto para solucionarlo tengo que activar el servicio *OracleServiceORCL*, pero he aquí mi problema ya que no tengo ningún servicio de Oracle y no sé que hacer...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has probado reinstalar? ¿Reiniciar la computadora?

Comment: Como digo lo acabo de instalar, y también ya reinicié la PC y nada ...

Comment: ¿esta activo el listener? Eso lo vez ejecutando: lsnrctl status

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, tu lo pudiste solucionar?

Comment: @NicoleUreña sí, hice lo de la respuesta instalando Oracle XE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta instalando oracle XE aparte del que ya instalaste
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html

yo instale sql developer y tampoco me salian los servicios hasta que instale XE